# COUNT in a WHERE statement SQL

Tags: sql, count, having-clause

My Table consists of 3 columns; id, state, carColour, and over 1mil rows.
I want to return all states which have more black cars than white cars.

I have tried:

```
SELECT state
FROM table
WHERE state IN (SELECT state
                FROM table
                WHERE COUNT(carColour = 'Black') > COUNT(carColour = 'White'))
GROUP BY state
```

But obviously a count() in a where statement doesnt work... How can I solve this?

Comment: You want `having` not `where`

Comment: What type of database is it? SQL server? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a subquery. You can filter in the `having` clause, using conditional aggreation:

```
select state
from mytable
group by state
having sum(case when carColour = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) 
     > sum(case when carColour = 'White' then 1 else 0 end)
```

This uses standard `case` syntax, which is supported pretty much everywhere. Some databases have shortcuts. For example, Postgres and SQLite support the `filter` clause:

```
having count(*) filter(where carColour = 'Black') 
     > count(*) filter(where carColour = 'White')
```

Comment: first one works. Filter seems to not be working even tho Im using sqlite. Thanks!

Comment: @broccoli: you need SQLite 3.30.0 for the `filter` clause...